# Firebase - How I can know first and last key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my project, I must know first and last key of child to do something. I have query same below, I use 'i' to find first but I don't know how to get last key? Have any ways to set if Firebase query complete will do function with `child_added`? .In test, `console.log(last)` but is `undefinded`

```
var i = 0; 
                myDataRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot){
                    if( i == 0)
                    {
                        first = snapshot.key;
                    }


                    renderInfo(snapshot.key, snapshot.val(), 'new');
                    last = snapshot.key;


            });
console.log(last)
```

Comment: Consider making two queries, one with limitToFirst(1) and the other with limitToLast(1), ordering each of them as needed to know which is appropriately first or last.